# Exogenous shock that affects two groups differently

Tags: panel-data, difference-in-difference

I want to know if difference in difference is appropriate for my research question, if not, what would you suggest instead?

I have two groups of observations (let's call them group A and group B) with an exogenous policy shock that occurred in 2005.

The policy have several provisions: some provisions affect both  groups. Some provisions affect group A only, while some provisions affect only group B.

I want to measure how the policy shock affected group A, as compared to group B.
Can I run Difference in Difference comparing both groups, or should I run only Fixed(or Random) effect limiting the data to only group A?

Thanks,